# Converting a certain SQL query into relational algebra

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

Doing an assignment for my database course and I want to double check my relational algebra.

The SQL:

```sql
SELECT dato, SUM(pris*antall) AS total
FROM produkt, ordre
WHERE ordre.varenr = produkt.varenr
GROUP BY dato
HAVING total >= 10000
```

The relational algebra:

```
σ total >= 10000 (
  ρ R(dato, total)(
    σ ordre.varenr = produkt.varenr (
      dato ℑ SUM(pris*antall (produkt x ordre)
    )
  )
)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: A closing parenthesis is missing. Presumably you mean `SUM(pris*antall)`?

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Define "convert"--Same result? Same structure? Nested algebra calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when a process allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your reference. [ask] [Help] [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: Just as an FYI this is question is 10 years old. I appreciate that you do not agree with how the question was asked, but at the time there was no additional information to give. There was no textbook even. I also think changing someone's tone of voice by brute forcing in an edit is also quite distasteful.

Comment: Hi. I know about the age. But people come here, so I am trying to help them. Re the edit, I edit so much bad writing that I try to reduce to a minimum--and I write this with no knowledge of how I edited this particular question--typically with no apparent purposeful effective style in sight, rather, rambling, equivocation, redundancy & sloppiness. Moreover, dry, straightforward & less is more when it comes to technical writing, plusI do try to leave original turns of phrase that aren't noise. Roll back / restore the prose if you want. I cannot agree that taking offence is appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know.  And anybody else is not likely to know either.

RA courses typically limit themselves to the selection, projection and join operators.  Aggregations are not typically covered by an RA course.  There even isn't any standard approach (that I know of) that the RA takes on aggregations.

What is the operator that your course defines for doing aggregations on relations ?  What type of value does that operator produce for its result ?  A relation ?  Something else ?  If something else, how does your course explain doing relational restrictions on that result, given that these result values aren't relations, but restriction works only on relations ?

Algebraically, this case starts with a natural join (produkt x ordre).

[The result of] this natural join is subjected to an aggregation operation.  Thus this natural join is to appear where you specify the relational input argument to your aggregation operator.  The other needed specs for specifying the aggregation are the output attribute names (total), and the way to compute them (SUM(...)).  Those might appear in subscript next to your aggregation operator symbol as "annotations", much like the attribute lists on projection and the restriction condition on restriction.  But anything concerning this operator is course-specific, because there isn't any agreed-upon standard notation for aggregations, as far as I know.

Then if your aggregation operator is defined to return a relation, you can specify your aggregation result as the input argument to a restriction with condition "total>=10000".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! According to our lectures slides our teacher uses ℑ for aggregation. For example SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dvd would be ℑ COUNT *(DVD). "What type of value does that operator produce for its result?" - I'm not sure what this means. I think what he wants is to be able to read what the SQL query would be from the RA.

Comment: Yeah.  I was afraid something like that was going to be the answer.  I'm afraid your lecturer might even be clueless as to what an algebra really is (an algebra is a set of operators that is closed over some set of types.  Relational algebra is a set of operators that is closed over some set of types that includes the relation type(s).).  Relational algebra is more than some cryptic and/or impenetrable way of writing SQL.  I really wonder what purpose all these teachers think they achieve by letting students "translate SQL into RA".  It's the biggest exercise in futility I can imagine.

Comment: Thanks again, we do not either understand why we are learning this.

Comment: For example.  What provisions are there in that symbology for writing down the attribute name for the COUNT() or the SUM() ?  (An attribute in a relation MUST have a name, and any RA notation for operators that return relations, MUST provide for those attribute names.)  What provisions are there in that symbology for doing multiple aggregations in a single go ?  (Genre SELECT COUNT(1), SUM(nummer) FROM ...)  Are those lectures or slides online anywhere ?

Comment: Eurhm, don't misunderstand me.  I'm not saying it is pointless to learn and understand RA.  Quite the contrary.  RA is foundational.  SQL is not.  It's the order of things they are getting wrong.  RA should come first, and "translation", if any, should be from RA to SQL.

Comment: The slides are online on the schools network, so you need a user to be able to access them. And the only examples he has of converting aggregation to RA is one at the time, he just lists all of the different aggregations and then shows an example of it being used in a query and the following RA.

  ℑAL(R) where AL is an aggregate function list

And then proceeding with examples

  ℑ COUNT rating(DVD)
  SELECT COUNT(rating)
  FROM DVD